# Running Vs code or code-server on raspberry pi 0 w

Tags: pi-zero-w, vs-code

I wanted to use vs code or code-server on my raspberry pi 0 w, I know that they is not compatible and that the board is not very powerful, has anyone found a way to install vs code or code-server etc on a raspberry pi 0 w (headless to be precise). I have also tried sshfs and sftp extensions but most of the time they disconnect and do cause lot's of problems. If somebody has been able to achieve this or know any supported alternatives to vs code that run on raspberry pi 0 w, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: *I want to drive my Citroën 2CV in the monaco grand prix* - not going to happen

Comment: ok thanks, I get the point.